# Jenkins JobDSL cannot be used to configure Maven properties

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I manage several hundred jobs using Jenkins JobDSL (plugin version 1.70) on a Jenkins 2.140 installation, running in a Docker container on an Ubuntu host.

I'm migrating some jobs from another Jenkins instance and some require Maven properties to be specified. The properties can easily be specified using the Jenkins UI, however the JobDSL does not have this option, meaning the configure block needs to be used.

After many hours of trial and error with the configure block I am unable to get this to work. The block I have settled on that I expect to work is below.

```
steps {
    maven {
        mavenInstallation('Maven 3 - Latest')
        rootPOM('pom.xml')
        goals('clean deploy')
        configure { node ->
            node / properties ('asdasd') {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect this to deliver this in the config.xml:

```
<builders>
<hudson.tasks.Maven>
<targets>clean install</targets>
<mavenName>(Default)</mavenName>
<pom>docker/app/pom.xml</pom>
<properties>
asdasd
</properties>
```

Based on the fact that I use the exact same configure block in another job to do something else:

```
steps {
    maven {
        mavenInstallation('Maven 3 - Latest')
        goals('clean deploy')
        configure { node ->
            node / injectBuildVariables ('false') {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which results in:

```
<builders>
<hudson.tasks.Maven>
<targets>clean deploy</targets>
<mavenName>Maven 3 - Latest</mavenName>
<jvmOptions/>
<usePrivateRepository>false</usePrivateRepository>
<injectBuildVariables>false</injectBuildVariables>
</hudson.tasks.Maven>
</builders>
```

However when I run a seed job which processes the DSL script in the hope of including the Maven properties, I get the below nondescript error output:

```
Processing provided DSL script
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:239)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.Item.getProperties(Item.groovy:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaBeanProperty.getProperty(MetaBeanProperty.java:59)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1243)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1215)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractContext.invokeMethod(AbstractContext.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeOnDelegationObjects(ClosureMetaClass.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:371)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeOnDelegationObjects(ClosureMetaClass.java:446)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:371)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeOnDelegationObjects(ClosureMetaClass.java:446)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:371)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeOnDelegationObjects(ClosureMetaClass.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:369)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
    at script$_run_closure1$_closure2$_closure3$_closure4.doCall(script:8)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.ContextHelper$_executeConfigureBlock_closure1.doCall(ContextHelper.groovy:25)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.ContextHelper$_executeConfigureBlock_closure1.doCall(ContextHelper.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2098.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:408)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.access$400(GroovyCategorySupport.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:250)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.use(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$755.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite$StaticMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:151)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.callStatic(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:214)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.ContextHelper.executeConfigureBlock(ContextHelper.groovy:24)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.ContextHelper$executeConfigureBlock$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.ContextHelper$executeConfigureBlock$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepContext.maven(StepContext.groovy:483)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2388.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:384)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at script$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(script:3)
    at script$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(script)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.ContextHelper.executeInContext(ContextHelper.groovy:16)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.ContextHelper$executeInContext.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.ContextHelper$executeInContext.call(Unknown Source)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.Project.steps(Project.groovy:260)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2278.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:384)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at script$_run_closure1.doCall(script:2)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.with(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:242)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$757.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:251)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:76)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.JobParent.processItem(JobParent.groovy:105)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2224.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.JobParent.freeStyleJob(JobParent.groovy:46)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.JobParent$freeStyleJob$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.JobParent$freeStyleJob$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.JobParent.job(JobParent.groovy:38)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslFactory$job.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
    at script.run(script:1)
    at script$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at script$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader.runScript(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:132)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2223.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader.runScriptEngine(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:106)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2204.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:384)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader$_runScripts_closure1.doCall(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:59)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2201.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2040)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2025)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2078)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$164.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader.runScripts(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:46)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.ExecuteDslScripts.perform(ExecuteDslScripts.java:341)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1815)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
ERROR: null
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s
Started calculate disk usage of build
Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
Started calculate disk usage of workspace
Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
Finished: FAILURE
```

Seems strange the JobDSL doesn't support Maven properties (unless I'm missing something) and even stranger that this configure block isn't working. Can anyone see what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this just because I've lost almost an hour to figure out why configure block with `properties` element does not work. The `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` problem was resolved after adding single quotes to *properties*. So the working configure block for the example from question would be:

```
configure { node ->
            node / 'properties' ('asdasd') {
            }
        }
```

**Edit:**
Even official JobDSL plugin documentation mentions it (https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/master/docs/The-Configure-Block.md#transforming-xml).

> Groovy key words (e.g. switch), methods each object inherits (e.g. properties) and element names containing operators (e.g. .) must be put into quotes:

Answer (score 0):

On another forum, I discovered that you need to use `property` rather than `properties` so 
 you don't need the configure block at all. This is very hard to find in the api viewer so I missed it. It doesn't address why that code wasn't working, but the correct way to do this is:

```
        steps {
            maven {
                mavenInstallation('Maven 3 - Latest')
                goals('clean install')
                rootPOM('docker/orqa/pom.xml')
                property('String key' ,'String value')
                property('String key' ,'String value')
            }
        }
```